# opennebula 5.2 sunstone Fail, need help to troubleshoot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, frontend, opennebula

I am trying to install and test opennebula 5.2 on a single machine
Fresh installation of CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

I followed step by step guideline from 
http://docs.opennebula.org/5.2/deployment/opennebula_installation/frontend_installation.html

opennebula is running
libvirtd is running 
 but 
opennebula-sunstone fails to start

it is not creating /var/log/on/sunstone.error
and only a single line in /var/log/sunstone.log

```
# Logfile created on 2016-12-30 12:52:59 -0500 by logger.rb/41954
```

and here is output when I try to check status by

$ `systemctl status opennebula-sunstone`

```
opennebula-sunstone.service - OpenNebula Web UI Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/opennebula-sunstone.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-01-02 12:40:22 EST; 12h ago

Process: 32619 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/one/sunstone/sunstone-server.rb (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Process: 32614 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /tmp/logrotate.state -f /etc/logrotate.d/opennebula (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Main PID: 32619 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain ruby[32619]: from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_...re'

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain ruby[32619]: from /usr/lib/one/sunstone/routes/vcenter.rb:26:in ...)>'

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain ruby[32619]: from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_...re'

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain ruby[32619]: from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_...re'

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain ruby[32619]: from /usr/lib/one/sunstone/sunstone-server.rb:441:i...n>'

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain ruby[32619]: from /usr/lib/one/sunstone/sunstone-server.rb:440:i...ch'

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain ruby[32619]: from /usr/lib/one/sunstone/sunstone-server.rb:440:i...n>'

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: opennebula-sunstone.service: main process exited, co...URE

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit opennebula-sunstone.service entered failed state.

Jan 02 12:40:22 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: opennebula-sunstone.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the dependencies `yum install ruby rubygems rubygem-nokogiri rubygem-json rubygem-rack rubygem-sequel rubygem-sinatra rubygem-sqlite3-ruby rubygem-thin rubygem-uuidtools json sequel sqlite3`

This should resolve the dependency errors of Sunstone